# CakePHP: Removing Redundancy In Database Tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on models using cakephp. I have two models, the post model; which contains a $hasMany relationship with the tags model. I want the tags name value to be a unique. This is to remove any data redundancy. I want to make it searchable via a AJAX like search box for the tags. I need to be able to automatically create the tags on the fly, but only if they have not already been created. How do i achieve this with CakePHP 2.6.1?

Example:
I have created two tables:

tags:

```
id    name    post_id
```

posts:

```
id    title    url    content
```

Comment: What CakePHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using CakePHP Version 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure that the `name` value of any tag is unique, simply add a [validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) to the `Tag` model for the name field. There is a specific [isUnique](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique) validation rule. In your `app/Model/Tag.php` file, add this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'message' => 'This tag already exists.'
    )
);
```

That will cause any save operation on the Tag model with a duplicate tag name to fail with the error message you set in the model.

To make it ignore any duplicates, slightly change the way your save works. Add something like this to your Controller logic:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Tags'] as $tagData) {
    $this->Tag->set($tagData);
    if ($this->Tag->validates()) {
        $this->Tag->create();
        $this->Tag->save($tagData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it ignore the unique fields? ie when i run $this->model-saveall(...) it will still use the unique values but it will only create the new tags?

Comment: "You can validate that a set of fields are unique by providing multiple fields and set $or to false" will this do that?

Comment: @DanielSamson That works slightly different, but can be done. See my updated answer. You can check each tag's validation rules seperately and choose to only try a `save()` if it passed and do nothing otherwise.